# EF CodeFirst self-referential Many-to-Many...on abstract or derived classes

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to model a self-referencing many to many in EF CodeFirst with a polymorphic table structure.  I'm using the October 2011 CTP which supports navigation properties on derived types (which works well in other tests I've done).

The problem:

When I set up this particular many to many relationship in the base (abstract) table's mapping and try to get related records, I get a SQL query with hundreds of K of unions and joins...just the time taken to generate the SQL statement is 30 seconds, compared to bare milliseconds to execute it.  However, it does return appropriate results.  When I change the many to many to exist between two derived objects, the query produced is perfect...but I can't map the same relating M2M table again for other derived objects without being informed that the joining table has "already been mapped".

Specifics:

An existing database structure has a base table--Party--which is joined 1...1 or 0 with Customer, Vendor, User, and Department (each a type of Party).

Parties are related to each other via an existing join table PartyRelationship (ID, InternalPartyID, ExternalPartyID).  By convention, InternalPartyID contains a User's PartyID and ExternalPartyID contains the PartyID of the Customer, Vendor, or Department with which they are associated.

Trying to use EF CodeFirst in a new project (WCF DataServices), I have created the Party class as:

```
public abstract class Party
{
    public Party()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
        this.PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
        this.InternalRelatedParties = new List<Party>();
        this.ExternalRelatedParties = new List<Party>();
}

    public int PartyID { get; set; }
    public short Active { get; set; }
    //other fields common to Parties

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Party> InternalRelatedParties { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Party> ExternalRelatedParties { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using TPT inheritance, Customer, Vendor, Department and User are similar to:

```
public class Customer : Party
{
    public string TermsCode { get; set; }
    public string DefaultFundsCode { get; set; }
    //etc
}

public class User : Party
{
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

The joining table:

```
public class PartyRelationship
{
    public int PartyRelationshipID { get; set; }
    public int InternalPartyID { get; set; }
    public int ExternalPartyID { get; set; }
    //certain other fields specific to the relationship
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class PartyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Party>
{
    public PartyMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.PartyID);

        // Properties
        this.ToTable("Party");
        this.Property(t => t.PartyID).HasColumnName("PartyID");
        this.Property(t => t.Active).HasColumnName("Active");
        //etc

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(p => p.InternalRelatedParties)
           .WithMany(rp => rp.ExternalRelatedParties)
           .Map(p => p.ToTable("PartyRelationship")
           .MapLeftKey("ExternalPartyID")
           .MapRightKey("InternalPartyID"));
    }
}

public class PartyRelationshipMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PartyRelationship>
{
    public PartyRelationshipMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.PartyRelationshipID);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        //this.ToTable("PartyRelationship"); // Commented out to prevent double-mapping
        this.Property(t => t.PartyRelationshipID).HasColumnName("PartyRelationshipID");
        this.Property(t => t.InternalPartyID).HasColumnName("InternalPartyID");
        this.Property(t => t.ExternalPartyID).HasColumnName("ExternalPartyID");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateTime).HasColumnName("CreateTime");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateByID).HasColumnName("CreateByID");
        this.Property(t => t.ChangeTime).HasColumnName("ChangeTime");
        this.Property(t => t.ChangeByID).HasColumnName("ChangeByID");
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base("name=MyDBName")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(null);
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Party> Parties { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PartyMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PartyRelationshipMap());
    }
}
```

A URL such as http://localhost:29004/Services/MyDataService.svc/Parties(142173)/SAData.Customer/InternalRelatedParties eventually returns correct oData but takes 30 seconds to produce an enormous SQL statement (189K) that executes in 600 ms.

I've also tried mapping the PartyRelationship table with a bidirectional one to many (both to Party as the "one" table), but with a similar outcome.

Do I need separate join tables for Customer-User, Vendor-User, and Department-User?  Should I look at vertical table splitting or database views that separates PartyRelationship into separate logical entities (so I can remap the same table)?  Is there another way the EF model should be configured in this scenario?

Comment: I am afraid it's not your fault but EF's and you cannot do that much to improve the performance, unless you abandon TPT inheritance. Queries over TPT models are known to be horrible: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx and http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015337-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-performance As far as I know they are going to fix the problem of those slowly generated monster queries in .NET 4.5

Comment: BTW: If `PartyRelationship` is an entity in your model which includes additional fields in addition to the key properties you must map two one-to-many relationships, not a single many-to-many. But it won't really fix your problem, as you said that you already tested it.

Comment: Thanks, Slauma for those links - directly relevant and informative.  FYI, however, the EF team blogged an update to the 8/17/2010 entry you reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/25/generated-sql-improvements-for-tpt-queries.aspx

Comment: Update: just installed EF 4.3 beta 1 and SQL generation time is down to 5-6 seconds and 29ms to execute.  Better!  Not quite "enough"...but definite improvement!

Comment: Yes, I know this new blog post (June 2011 CTP). Afaik they wanted to finally release the TPT improvements in .NET 4.5. I'm surprised that EF 4.3 beta 1 seems to be so much better regarding TPT because I thought it includes only Code First Migrations. (I've totally lost overview about EF versions, CTPs, alphas, betas and what not, to be honest.) Anyway, very interesting result! You could post your measurements as an answer and accept your own answer. The result is interesting for everyone, I think.

Comment: It's an improvement, but I'd still like to know if there's a better answer from a model design point of view (5 seconds is still not acceptable response rate for what should be a simple join query).  Will leave the question open to answers from other perspectives for a while.